# ASP.NET CORE GIVES A WARNING This package may not be fully compatible with your project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget-package

I am working on an asp.net core project and i have installed a nuget package which is in .net framework. but on rebuild it gives the following error:

> warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

should i converted the package into dot net standard ? or is there anything else

Comment: This is not an ASP .NET Core package, but the old ASP .Net WebApi 2 for the old ASP .NET. Don't use this package for ASP .NET Core.

Comment: More generally, that type of error means you're including a package that targets .NET Framework instead of either .NET Core or a compatible version of .NET Standard.

Comment: But that package is only available in Dot Net Framework 4.6.1 and I want to use it in ASP.NET CORE How can i do it.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't. It's for ASP.NET Web Api, not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I have the package code. Is there a way to convert the package into dot net standard and then utilize it.

Comment: Why do you want it? If it’s just about WebAPI for ASP .NET Core, then you don’t need it as WebAPI is already inbuilt.

Comment: Does this particular package have something that does not exist in ASP.NET Core?

It should be much easier to port the code to work with the Asp.Net Core packages instead of rewriting the Asp. Net packages.